# Will the grpc server class be created multiple times?

Tags: c#, grpc

[offical demo here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/basics/#implementing-routeguide)

```
// RouteGuideImpl provides an implementation of the RouteGuide service.
public class RouteGuideImpl : RouteGuide.RouteGuideBase
{
    ...
}
```

My question is, will `RouteGuideImpl` be created once? or multiple times? Is it guaranteed to be singleton? I didn't find the answer from the docs.

Comment: If you look at how the server is started, the code creates a single instance itself to pass to `BindService`. I think it would be very odd to require the user to create one instance, but then the framework automatically create more.

Comment: A route is is instructions in the client code indicating the number of webpages that are used at the server.  Depending on the server you can have one or more webpages.  A request has parameters and a route.  A server that does multiple functions can be designed to either use either parameters and/or routes for the client to sent commands to the server on which function is to be used for a query.  Suppose you had a website that allowed people to buy either cars or groceries.  Would you have one webpage or two webpages?  That is a design issue.  So you may have one route or two routes.

Comment: in the particular example you posted, the instances created by you will be directly registered by the server.